Hilt plugin problem with Android jetpack compose: "Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value."
I am using Hinl in my project and facing this error:

"Explain build error: [Hilt] Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (com.google.dagger.hilt. android)  See https://dagger.dev/hilt/ gradle- setup. html [1;31m[Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.[0m"

These are my plugins and dependencies:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
}

Dependencies:
implementation(libs.hilt.android.v2511)
kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
kapt(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler.v110)
implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.v110)

And this is my MainActivity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var permissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) {
            viewModel.loadWeatherInfo()
        }
        permissionLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        )

        setContent {
            ComposeWeatherAppTestTheme {
            }
        }
    }
}


The idea is to declare all plugins in your app-level gradle file, without actually applying them, like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    kotlin("kapt") apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
}

For each module you then only activate the plugins in their respective gradle file that you actually need, like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1"
}

You seem to have mixed this up by using apply false even in the module gradle file, therefore never actually applying it.

Btw., you should define that plugin in your version catalog, as you already have done with your other plugins and dependencies:
[versions]
hilt = "2.51.1"

[plugins]
hiltAndroid = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }

Then you can use alias(libs.plugins.hiltAndroid) instead of id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android").

for new version kotlin, Hilt, Compose use this:
In .toml I use:
[versions]
kotlin = "2.0.0"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.51.1"
hilt = "2.51.1"
navigation-compose = "1.2.0"

[libraries]
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { group = "androidx.hilt", name = "hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigation-compose" }


[plugins]
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version = "2.0.0-1.0.24" }

in gradle Module:app use:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp)
} 

android{
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.14"
    }
}
dependencies {
    //hilt
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
}

in gradle Top-level:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp) apply false
}

